# Skip over character in insert mode, even at the end of a line

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, cursor-movement

I have this map in my .vimrc:

```
inoremap <C-space> <C-o>l
```

So that, eg, if I'm in insert mode:

[image]

I can just type `<C-space>` to move out of parens:

[image]

It all works great in the *middle* of a line.  But if that `)` were the last character on the line, then the cursor won't move when I hit `<C-space>`.  Which makes sense, because there is nowhere for it move to.

But what I *want* in this case is for `<C-space>` to behave as if I'd typed `<esc>$a` -- ie, gone to the end of the line in normal mode and pressed `a` to start appending characters.

How can I update my mapping to achieve this special behavior for the end of line case?

Comment: Why did you create that mapping when you already have right  `<right>`?

Comment: Just in case you were wondering: `<C-O>a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to simply change your mapping to:

```
inoremap <C-space> <C-o><Space>
```

`<Space>` moves forward one character even when at end of line.

Comment: `" insert mode: escape to normal mode, move 1 char and enter insert mode`  
`inoremap <c-l> <Esc>la`  
`" normal mode: skip a character and enter insert mode`  
`nnoremap <c-l> a`  

I have used these mappings. I know Ctrl+right arrow does the job. But arrow keys are not so close to the home row. Please do suggest if you have any other key bindings. :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can simply set `:set virtualedit=onemore` and your mapping will start to work even at the line end case.